# how to make custom directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angularjs ,building my first angular app now i want to display  the data which i displayed right now in a table using  a customized directive.
can anyone tell me how can i do this?
i just want to have a custom directive and all data should be displayed using that directive.
is customized directive should placed in a separate file?
please guide me how can i do it?

here is my controller:

```
'use strict';

 app.controller('myAppCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
 $scope.names = []

 $http.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/new.json')
     .success(function (response) {
     $scope.names = response.data.children;
 })
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rr6q0umb/4/

Comment: @alecxe can you tell me

Comment: @finspin can you tell me how this can be done here is my app code https://jsfiddle.net/rr6q0umb/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go through some resources online to study about angular directives .

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_custom_directives.htm

Simple directive approach for beginners 
 //Controller

```
 app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.name = 'World';
 });
```

//Directive

```
app.directive('simpleDemo',function(){
var newtemplate = function(){
 var template = '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"><i>';
 return template;
 }
return {
restrict: 'E',
template: newtemplate
}
})
```

//html

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
<button><simple-demo></simple-demo></button>
```

Comment: here is my app https://jsfiddle.net/rr6q0umb/4/ i want to display data using custom directive which is i displaying now in simple html table

Answer (score 0):

It might help you!

```
    <html>
    <head>
       <title>Angular JS Custom Directives</title>
    </head>

       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
       <script>
          var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

          mainApp.directive('student', function() {
             var directive = {};
             directive.restrict = 'E';
             directive.template = "Student: <b>{{student.name}}</b> , Roll No: <b>{{student.rollno}}</b>";

             directive.scope = {
                student : "=name"
             }

             directive.compile = function(element, attributes) {
                element.css("border", "1px solid #cccccc");

                var linkFunction = function($scope, element, attributes) {
                   element.html("Student: <b>"+$scope.student.name +"</b> , Roll No: <b>"+$scope.student.rollno+"</b><br/>");
                   element.css("background-color", "#ff00ff");
                }

                return linkFunction;
             }

             return directive;
          });

          mainApp.controller('StudentController', function($scope) {
                $scope.Mahesh = {};
                $scope.Mahesh.name = "Mahesh Parashar";
                $scope.Mahesh.rollno  = 1;

                $scope.Piyush = {};
                $scope.Piyush.name = "Piyush Parashar";
                $scope.Piyush.rollno  = 2;
          });

       </script>
<body>
       <h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>
       <div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="StudentController">
            <student name="Mahesh"></student><br/>
            <student name="Piyush"></student>
       </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Reference URLs:

https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/creating-components-p3-angular2-directives
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/custom-directives.html

http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/

Comment: (function () {
    'use strict';
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
        .controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.sortType     = '';
        $scope.sortReverse  = true;
        $http.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/new.json")
            .success(function (response) {
                $scope.stories = response.data.children;
            });
    }])
        .directive('myData', function() {
            return {
                templateUrl: 'DataTable.html'
            };
        }); here is my controller which i changed @anil

Comment: here is my DataTable.html <ul>
    <li ><table  width="80%" id="dataTable" align="center" name="table1"> <tr>
                 <td><strong>Title</strong></td>
                 <td><strong>Link</strong></td>
                 <td><strong>Score</strong></td>
             </tr>
             <tr ng-repeat="x in names |filter:test|orderBy:sortExpression:order ">
<td id="title"><a  ng-href="{{ x.data.url}}">{{x.data.title}}</a></td> <td ><a ng-href="{{ x.data.url}}">Link</a></td>
                 <td>{{x.data.score}}</td>
             </tr>
         </table>
    </li>
</ul>

Comment: myapp = angular.module("myapp", []);

myapp.directive('userinfo', function() {
    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'E'; /* restrict this directive to elements */
    directive.templateUrl = "/myapp/html-templates/div-template.html";

    return directive;
});

Comment: here is my index page now looks  <div my-data></div>
        </div>

Comment: Put simply  directive.templateUrl ="DataTable.html"; and  HTML is <userinfo></userinfo>, here "userinfo" is name of directive

Comment: flow this link steps, will help you http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/custom-directives.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84793/discussion-between-anil-singh-and-hassan).